# SimpleXML, convert children with dynamic names to list

Tags: java, android, simple-framework

I'm using SimpleXML 
http://simple.sourceforge.net/home.php
 inside my Android app,

Im getting back data from API like this :

```
<Items>
   <data_0>
      <name> x1 </name>
      <phone> y1 </phone>
   </data_0>
   <data_1>
      <name> x2 </name>
      <phone> y2 </phone>
   </data_1>
   <data_2> ... </data_2>
      ...
   <data_n> ... </data_n>
</Items>
```

How I can write POJO class with simpleXML so that it accepts infinite number of `<data_n>` elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a horribly designed XML document and if you have any influence over the format you're receiving I'd suggest requesting a change to:

```
<Items>
   <data id="0">
      <name> x1 </name>
      <phone> y1 </phone>
   </data>
   <data id="1">
      <name> x2 </name>
      <phone> y2 </phone>
   </data>
   <data id="2"> ... </data>
      ...
   <data id="n"> ... </data>
</Items>
```

Personally I wouldn't even try to design the POJO for this and instead just clean up the XML (even simply by using string pattern replacement in it's string representation) to the format above (you can even get rid of the `id` attribute completely as place on the list will reflect it anyway), which subsequently can be defined as a `List` of data objects.

Unless you can guarantee a certain maximum number of `data` elements (then copy&paste for dozens of horribly named elements can do the trick), I don't think you can even design a POJO for this, since you can't also define the XML Schema for this document.

Comment: Thanks Norbert! yeah its a mess :/